# Locating merged cell ranges in openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I'm working on extracting some data from a `.xlsx` file using openpyxl and Pandas.

I can't find a cell property (or indeed any other information) that indicates where I can find out which cells are merged in the spreadsheets. How do I know which cells are merged together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**(EDITED to fully answer the question and update 2018-08-31).**

If you want to know which ranges are merged you can examine the `merged_cells.ranges` worksheet attribute, which is a list of
`openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.CellRange` objects.

The CellRange object implements `__contains__`, so it's possible
to see whether cell `A3` is part of a cell range by evaluating

```
any('A3' in rng for rng in ws.merged_cells.ranges)
```

To find out which range it's a part of:

```
for rng in ws.merged_cells.ranges:
    if 'A3' in rng:
        break
else:
    rng = None
```

The content of a merged cell is actually stored against the top-left cell in
the range. Accessing that is left as an exercise for the reader, as is using other
forms of cell reference than the standard Excel strings.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem (to me) to help much. Two adjacent cells might both be merged, but in different merge groups. How do I tell which group a given cell is in (i.e. which other cells it is merged with?)

Comment: I see that a worksheet has a `merged_cell_ranges` property which looks as thought it might be what I want.

Comment: ah, that wasn't quite what you asked. You should easily be able to write something based on the code for `merged_cells`

Comment: Thanks. That information was useful enough to be edited into your answer (and I've changed the question slightly to make my meaning clearer).

Comment: @holdenweb how does the code in the answer tell you what group your cell is in?  doesn't it just return a boolean?

Comment: OK, does the expanded answer tell you how?